# After moving Laravel 5 project from XAMPP to Ubuntu server the views cannot be found

Tags: laravel-5

Working on XAMPP everything seems to work fine, but now that I moved the project to our internal Ubuntu server I am getting errors that views cannot be found. While developing I moved the views directory to app/Views (instead of public/views) and changed this in config/view.php as below:

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(app_path('Views'))
]
```

And the error is:

```
[2015-11-02 16:33:42] local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'View [base\frontend\baywest2015\pages\page] not found.' in /var/www/baywest2015/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/baywest2015/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(77): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('base\\frontend\\b...', Array)
#1 /var/www/baywest2015/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(145): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('base\\frontend\\b...')
#2 /var/www/baywest2015/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(592): Illuminate\View\Factory->make('base\\frontend\\b...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/baywest2015/app/Http/Controllers/Frontend/PagesController.php(63): view('base\\frontend\\b...', Array)
#4 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\PagesController->page()
```

So at first I thought this is a typical capital letter issue, but everywhere I look, the Views is set with a capital V.

Am I missing something?

By the way, moving from one XAMPP environment to another works great

Strange also is that the auth/login is found which is also in the app/Views directory

```
View [base\backend\login] not found. (View: /var/www/baywest2015/app/Views/auth/login.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

The deal is:

```
return view('base\frontend\\' . config('folder') . '\\pages.page', [
    'content' => $array
]);
```

On the XAMPP server it works fine, but on Ubuntu I need to change it into:

```
return view('base.frontend.' . config('folder') . '.pages.page', [
```